# Can human pathogens present on plants become plant pathogens?

Tags: botany, microbiology, virology, theoretical-biology, pathogenesis

Since human pathogens sometimes live on the surface of plant leaves(read [here](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/30444697/) and [and here](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/23406434/)), and there are plant-pathogen [microbes also living on leaf surfaces](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC91203/), is it possible for plant virulence genes to transfer to the human pathogens (perhaps via horizontal gene transfer) and make the human pathogen also pathogenic to plants? Has there ever been evidence of this happening?

[This review paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4411691/) addresses why plant pathogens haven't "crossed the Kingdom border" to being human pathogens, but what about the other way around (human pathogens affecting plants). Since there is such a wide array of plants out there with a wide range of pathogen interactions, it seems to me that it would be statistically more likely that a human pathogen could mutate to be pathogenic to some plant, than some plant pathogen could mutate to be pathogenic to specifically humans. Is that assumption valid? Also, I am talking about human-animals specifically, since it looks like [there is a known virus infects both animal and plant cells](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0217494) in the lab (Lepidoptera/ cow pea)

As a currently-relevant example, could some plant virus, say Southern Bean Mosaic Virus, somehow share genes with a coronavirus strain and become a morph plant-human pathogen? (I know this last question is a little "out-there"). I chose that example plant virus since [it is a positive-strand RNA virus](https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/10.1146/annurev-phyto-102313-050205) like [SARS-CoV-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Severe_acute_respiratory_syndrome_coronavirus_2). Thank you!